# Making a GET rest call for flickr api from xcode

Tags: xcode, json, api, rest, flickr

I'm trying to make a GET call using flickr.photos.getInfo method from an app. Goal is to get info about a photo using it's id.

my method:

```
+(NSDictionary*)photoForId:(NSString *)photoID
{
    NSLog(@"photo id = %@", photoID);
    NSString *request=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/flickr.photos.getInfo&photo_id=%@&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=original_format,tags,description,geo,date_upload,owner_name&page=1&method=flickr.photos.search", photoID];

        NSLog(@"output=%@",[self executeFlickrFetch:request]);
    return [[[self executeFlickrFetch:request]valueForKey:@"photos.photo"]lastObject];

}
```

executeFlickrFetch method:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)executeFlickrFetch:(NSString *)query
{
    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_key=%@", query, FlickrAPIKey];
    query = [query stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), query);
    NSData *jsonData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:query] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *results = jsonData ? [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error] : nil;
    return results;
}
```

Right now this call is returning null. I know execute fetch works because it is fetching photos by photographer, or place. Just need to figure out the photo id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the correct request:

```
NSString *request=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo&photo_id=%@&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=original_format,tags,description,geo,date_upload,owner_name&page=1", photoID];
```